# connected-react-router - You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, connected-react-router

Similar questions have been asked before but this seems to be specific to `connected-react-router`. I can use `Router` or `BrowserRouter` from `react-router(-dom)` and there is no issue but I want to incorporate Redux hence the use for this package.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { ConnectedRouter } from "connected-react-router";
// import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router";

// Routes
// import routes from "./js/routes";

// Components
import PimberlyLogin from "./js/containers/PimberlyLogin";
import CognitoLogin from "./js/containers/CognitoLogin";
import CognitoChangePassword from "./js/views/CognitoChangePassword";
import ListGroups from "./js/containers/ListGroups";
import VerificationCode from "./js/views/VerificationCode";

// Auth component
import { requireAuthentication } from "./js/components/AuthenticatedComponent";

// Styles
import "./css/app.css";

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={this.props.store}>
                <ConnectedRouter history={this.props.history}>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route
                          path="/"
                          component={PimberlyLogin}
                          exact={true}/>
                        <Route
                          path="/cognito/login"
                          component={CognitoLogin}
                          exact={true}/>
                        <Route
                          path="/cognito/changePassword"
                          component={CognitoChangePassword}
                          exact={true}/>
                        <Route
                          path="/groups"
                          component={requireAuthentication(ListGroups)}
                          exact={true}/>
                        <Route
                          path="/cognito/verificationCode"
                          component={VerificationCode}
                          exact={true}/>
                    </Switch>
                </ConnectedRouter>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

Relatively straight-forward and similar to what `connected-react-router` have as an [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connected-react-router#step-2) on the NPM page.

Even if I look at the [basic example](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/tree/master/examples/basic/src) on their GitHub, there is a similar coding pattern.

These are the errors I am getting:

[image]

The 2nd error seems like it might be originating from my higher-order component so this is the code:

**PimberlyLogin.js**

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

import PimberlyLoginComponent from "../views/PimberlyLogin";

import { setUsersPersist } from "../actions/user";
import { setGroupsPersist } from "../actions/group";

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    return {
        users: state.user,
        groups: state.group
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators({
        setUsersPersist: () => setUsersPersist(),
        setGroupsPersist: () => setGroupsPersist()
    });
};

export default withRouter(connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(PimberlyLoginComponent));
```

**EDIT**

I played around with grabbing `<Switch>` and `<Route>` from different packages *(`react-router` & `react-router-dom`)*. At the moment I am doing:

```
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router";
```

...and am getting: *`You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>.`*

If I do:

```
import { Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Route } from "react-router";
```

I get: *`You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router>.`*

Is this potentially an issue with how `<Route>` from `react-router` plays with `connected-react-router`?

Versions:

- `react-router` @ v4.3.1
- `react-router-dom` @ v4.4.0-beta
- `connected-react-router` @ v6.0.0
- `react` @ v16.5.2

Comment: I was looking at their examples, and I have no idea why this would work, but they seem to wrap their <Switch> components in a div or fragment when setting it up. Try doing that.

Comment: I have attempted doing that and the same error messages appear.

Comment: I'm having the same problem at the moment. Have you been able to solve this?

Answer (score 6):

I think this is because you're using 2 versions of `react-router` (4.3.1 for the core router & 4.4.0-beta for `react-router-dom`). I had the same problem. I removed `react-router` from my project (since it comes with `react-router-dom`) and used v4.3.1. It seemed to work fine after that.

All that is based off of [this response](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/issues/206#issuecomment-453808798) from `connected-react-router`'s maintainer

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
"react-router": "^4.3.1"
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same issue some years later when migrating an existing package to an npm workspaces monorepo.
Removing `react-router` (as suggested by @gonzofish) didn't work for me, but removing it and upgrading `react-router-dom` to v5 did.